How to show this double-sequence limit converge?
(I'm sorry there's a lot of definitions)
Let $W$ be a circular (so convex) open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, which center is a complex numbers $τ$.
$τ$ is an attractive fixed point of the function $f : W \rightarrow W$, holomorphic and injective.
Moreover, $0<|f'(τ)|<1$ (we write $λ=f'(τ)$)
We also have $\forall (x,y)\in W², |f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|$
(So every value in $W$ converges towards $τ$ when you iterate $f$)
I already managed to show that for any sequence $(u_n)$ such that $u_0\in W$ and $u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$,
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(\frac{u_{n+1}-τ}{u_n-τ})=λ$$
For any such sequence $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$
($a_0,b_0)\in W²$, $τ≠a_0≠b_0≠τ$, $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$, $b_{n+1}=f(b_n)$
$$\text{I'd like to show that}~\lim_{n\to+\infty}(\frac{a_{n}-τ}{b_n-τ}) ~~\text{converges}$$
And if true, not towards 0.
I tried using the inequality, but it doesn't work well for a quotient, and trying to use the other limit didn't really lead to anywhere else either. I haven't done any complex analysis, so I might not know an obvious theorem to use. So if anyone knows a useful theorem or trick to solve this, feel free to share.
